# Why does jQuery .insertAfter not work in this example?

Tags: jquery

In the following example, the alert shows, but the **#message is blank**.

If I **comment out** the .insertAfter line then the #message is displayed correctly.

**Why doesn't the .insertAfter work in this example?**

Firebug just steps right over it.

**javascript:**

```
google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");

//run when page is loaded
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {

    $('.languageChooser select').bind('click', function() {
        var numberOfItems = $('.languageChooser select option:selected').length;
        $('#message').hide().html("You have selected " + numberOfItems + " " + smartPlural('language',numberOfItems) + ".").fadeIn('slow');

        if(numberOfItems == 1) {
            $('#message').insertAfter('<div>Use the CTRL and SHIFT keys to select multiple items.</div>');
            alert('here');
        }
    });

    function smartPlural(itemName, numberOfItems) {
        if(numberOfItems == 1) {
            return itemName;
        } else {
            return itemName + 's';
        }
    }

});
```

**html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Text XHTML Page</title>
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/main.js"></script>       
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="languageChooser">
        <div class="title">Please choose a language:</div>
        <select size="4" multiple="multiple">
            <option>C#</option>
            <option>Ruby</option>
            <option>PHP</option>
            <option>VB.NET</option>
            <option>JavaScript</option>
            <option>Scala</option>
        </select>
        <div id="message"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[insertAfter](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/insertAfter) works only with elements already existing on the DOM, give a look to the documentation:

> The elements must already be inserted
>   into the document (you can't insert an
>   element after another if it's not in
>   the page).

Are you maybe looking for [append](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append) or [appendTo](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/appendTo)?

Comment: So if i have an element that i am creating dynamically and i want to insert it after an existing element(that is present in dom). Will it get added or not ?

Comment: @cafebabe1991 , yes it will be added after the mentioned element if the existing element is being shown or part of somewhere inside **<html><head>.....</head><body>....</body></html>**

Answer (score 4):

In jQuery we use `$(element).after([html])` and not `$(element).insertAfter([html])`.
Just change your code to this and it should work.

```
  google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
      $('.languageChooser select').bind('click', function() {
          var numberOfItems = $('.languageChooser select option:selected').length;
          $('#message').hide().html("You have selected " + numberOfItems + " " + smartPlural('language',numberOfItems) + ".").fadeIn('slow');
          if(numberOfItems == 1) {
                  //$('#message').insertAfter('Use the CTRL and SHIFT keys to select multiple items.');

                  $('#message').after('Use the CTRL and SHIFT keys to select multiple items.');
                  alert('here');
          }
      });
      function smartPlural(itemName, numberOfItems) {
          if(numberOfItems == 1) {
                  return itemName;
          } else {
                  return itemName + 's';
          }
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).ready(function() {

    //google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
    //run when page is loaded
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {

        $('.languageChooser select').bind('click', function() {
            var numberOfItems = $('.languageChooser select option:selected').length;
            $('#message').hide().html("You have selected " + numberOfItems + " " + smartPlural('language', numberOfItems) + ".").fadeIn('slow');

            if (numberOfItems == 1) {
                $('#message').append('Use the CTRL and SHIFT keys to select multiple items.');
                // alert('here');
            }
        });

        function smartPlural(itemName, numberOfItems) {
            if (numberOfItems == 1) {
                return itemName;
            } else {
                return itemName + 's';
            }
        }

    });
});
```

​

Above is the correct code. Use `append` insteed of `.insertAfter`.