# How to use .insertAfter on dynamic DOM elements with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So I'm attempting to dynamically add a row to a table using jQuery's `DOM` creation tools, when [I discovered that you cannot use the `insertAfter()` method on elements that have been dynamically created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507794/why-does-jquery-insertafter-not-work-in-this-example), rendering this:

```
var row = $('<tr></tr>')
  .append($('<td></td>', { html: firstVal })
      .insertAfter($('<td></td>', { html: secondVal  }) // This doesn't work!
      )
  );
```

useless, because that's exactly what I'm doing. Attempting to use `insertAfter` on a dynamic element.

What's the easiest and most effective solution to this which still produces clean code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you *can* use `insertAfter` on dynamically created DOM elements. Only they need to have a parent node, so that there is a tree in which the "next" element could be inserted. You are calling `insertAfter` on that `<td>` before having it appended to the `<tr>`. The following would work:

```
var td1 = $('<td></td>', { html: firstVal }),
    td2 = $('<td></td>', { html: secondVal });

var row = $('<tr></tr>').append(td1);
td1.insertAfter(td2);
```

However, what you actually want to do is use [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) multiple times:

```
var row = $('<tr></tr>')
    .append($('<td></td>', { html: firstVal }))
    .append($('<td></td>', { html: secondVal }));
```

ot even with multiple arguments:

```
var row = $('<tr></tr>')
    .append($('<td></td>', { html: firstVal }),
            $('<td></td>', { html: secondVal }));
```

Comment: Thank you. This should've been obvious.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you need to insert two cells in a row. You need to use both td elements in the `append` method.

```
<h2></h2>

    $(document).ready(function () {
    var row = $('<tr></tr>').append(($('<td></td>', { html: "test1" })), ($('<td></td>', { html: "test2" })));
    $("h2").append(row);
})
```

Comment: Do you need to have: <tr> <td> <td> </td> </td> </tr> ?

Comment: That's invalid markup. But it is what the code in your answer is doing (despite realising the OP's actual intention of inserting two cells in a row)

Comment: Thanks. I'd omit those superfluous parenthesis as well, but at least they're properly nested now :-)